# AWS s3 upload + api taking too long

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently, I'm using amazon s3 to store all the objects like images and videos. I'm using IOS AWS SDK to upload the objects.

The flow of my application are

1. User snaps a photo or record a video
2. User add additional information on a form, some sort like
   Instagram's caption (using Alamofire)
3. user clicks continue, and then AWS will begin to upload the images
   and videos to S3 using IOS AWS SDK
4. After object has been successfully uploaded to S3, S3 will response
   with a link
5. Finally using Alamofire to send the information including the link from
   S3 as parameters to POST API

The problem that I'm facing is that it takes quite some, to do AWS upload + calling an API. This indeed is a bad user experience. Most of the images are roughly less than 5 MB

My solution

1. Resizing the image, but what about Video?
2. After user click continue, instead of doing the AWS upload + calling
   API, why not do it as a background on a different screen, so that
   users don't need to wait for the loading indicator

What approach is great to solve this problem?. Thanks

Comment: Just an idea : why don't you begin the upload in the background when the user lands on the page where he writes the additional information ? And if he cancels or never posts it, you either cancel the upload if not finished, or send an order to delete it from the AWS db.

Comment: Check if AWS Cognito and the S3 bucket are in the same region. If those are in different regions it takes too long to upload content.

Comment: Try printing the link to the console when it is received. I'll bet the upload is faster than you think.  If that's the case then wrap your completion code in a Dispatch call to the main queue, and do the same for the AlamoFire completion handler.  I think the problem is not the speed of the transfers because your file is small, but the updating of the UI from a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be rephrased to a questions of "How do I minimise upload latency?"

*The most important thing is to use AWS for all app infrastructure.*

If you are using S3 as a file storage and uploading from external server, you'll face a huge impact on upload speed due network latency.

- When user uploads, your back-end process will write to disk first -
  use EBS SSD.
- Choose EC2 with increased network latency.
- Place all your AWS resources in the same region and same availability
  zone.

Another solution you might want to consider is to use S3 post-operation, instead of in-operation.

That simply means your server takes the upload and gives back URL to user, where independent background process syncs with S3 outside users requests.

In this situation you would have *User -> Server -> User*.

Right now you have *User -> Server -> S3 -> User*.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use content delivery network service like [AWS cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) when speed and user experience is of utmost importance.

Amazon S3 is ideal when low cost of bandwidth and storage is more critical than speed of access, whereas Cloudfront is all about speed of access.

Please see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html) link as to how to setup cloudfront with your S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

When your users are distributed worldwide, you should enable and use S3 Transfer Acceleration. This will decrease the upload time for user who are not close to your buckets's region.

Besides that, uploading 5 MB will take some time depending on your mobile connectivity. So you should resize the image on the client and you can think about starting the upload earlier, e.g. when the users enters details the upload already runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that including "region" in the config speeds up uploading in 7 seconds.

There are maybe other ways to improve, I'm currently researching about including direct endpoint URL. Or maybe that's it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was not providing the content type option in the upload function. Saved like 60+ seconds

Answer (score 0):

In my case [using dual-stack endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/dual-stack-endpoints.html#dual-stack-endpoints-sdks) improved the speed of all the s3 commands.